# Bootstrap: Specify column size on the parent element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Normally with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you specify the column size of the `<div>` on the element itself, like so:

```
<div id="attribute-value-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            Attribute 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            Value 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Multiple additional rows of attribute-value pairs -->
</div>
```

But e.g. when building a form with multiple rows of similarly styled attribute-value pairs, it would be beneficial to specify this on the parent element, like so:

```
<div id="attribute-value-container" class="first-col-sm-4 second-col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            Attribute 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Value 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Multiple additional rows of attribute-value pairs -->
</div>
```

...possibly with some classes on the `div`s that are supposed to receive styles.

Another way to do this would be to use the first row as a template, and to apply this style to subsequent rows.

I'm assuming this is not part of Bootstrap's core CSS. Is there a 3rd party CSS add-on library available? And has it been proposed for future Bootstrap versions (I added it myself just now to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19258))? Pointers to relevant libraries/documentation/discussion are appreciated.

(I assume this must have been raised by other people than myself, but I haven't found any threads. I guess I'm missing the correct keyword or term. Sorry if this is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap works with predefined classes, you should use these classes as intended.

> On my current template, I have 11 attribute-value pairs, so I would
>   save 20 ((11-1)*2) classes if I could specify this on a parent or
>   template element. This would improve brevity (and, in my opinion,
>   legibility) and reduce room for errors.

Bootstrap 4 is built with Sass so you can compile your own version, which better fits your situation. From the [documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/):

> To use our Gruntfile and run our documentation locally, you’ll need a copy of Bootstrap’s source files, Node, and Grunt. Follow these steps and you should be ready to rock:
>
> 1. Download and install Node, which we use to manage our dependencies.
> 2. Install the Grunt command line tools, grunt-cli, with npm install -g grunt-cli.
> 3. Navigate to the root /bootstrap directory and run npm install to install our local dependencies listed in package.json.
> 4. Install Ruby, install Bundler with gem install bundler, and finally run bundle install. This will install all Ruby dependencies, such as Jekyll and plugins.
>
> When completed, you’ll be able to run the various Grunt commands provided from the command line.

For your situation you can use Sass `@extend`, or Bootstrap's grid mixins.

**Sass `@extend`**
See http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend.

Sass code:

```
.attribute-value-container {
  @extend .container;
  > div { 
    @extend .row;
    > div:first-child {
      @extend .col-sm-4;
    }
    > div:last-child {
      @extend .col-sm-8;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use the HTML with only 1 `attribute-value-container` class:

```
<div class="attribute-value-container">
    <div>
        <div>
            Attribute 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Value 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Multiple additional rows of attribute-value pairs -->
</div>
```

In the above you HTML code is smaller, but your CSS has become larger. Extending adds the selector in the compiled CSS code.

The compiled CSS code for the `.row`s will look like that shown beneath now:

```
.row, .attribute-value-container > div {
  margin-left: -0.9375rem;
  margin-right: -0.9375rem; }
  .row::after, .attribute-value-container > div::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; }
```

Alternatively you can use Bootstrap's grid mixins, see also http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#sass-mixins:

Sass code:

```
 .attribute-value-container {
  @include make-container();
  > div { 
    @include make-row();
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { 

      > div {
        @include make-col();
      }

      > div:first-child {
        @include make-col-span(4);
      }

      > div:last-child {
        @include make-col-span(8);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
.attribute-value-container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0.9375rem;
  padding-right: 0.9375rem; }
  .attribute-value-container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both; }
  .attribute-value-container > div {
    margin-left: -0.9375rem;
    margin-right: -0.9375rem; }
    .attribute-value-container > div::after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both; }
    .attribute-value-container > div > div {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      min-height: 1px;
      padding-left: 0.9375rem;
      padding-right: 0.9375rem; }
    @media (min-width: 544px) {
      .attribute-value-container > div > div:first-child {
        width: 33.33333%; }
      .attribute-value-container > div > div:last-child {
        width: 66.66667%; } }
```

You can apply the above CSS code on the same HTML as used for the first solution.

Using mixins as above also makes your CSS code larger, but you can compile without the predefined grid classes for situations you only uses mixins for your grids:

Sass:

```
$enable-grid-classes: false;
@import "bootstrap.scss";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that will really be implemented by bootstrap as it could go up to N columns. Each row is specified as it could be different for each one. If you want something outside of this scaffolding its quite easy to do yourself using a bit of CSS and nth-child.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/54ko3Le6/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="attribute-value-container" class="cols">
        <div>
            Attribute 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Value 1
        </div>
        <div>
            Attribute 2
        </div>
        <div>
            Value 2
        </div>
    <!-- Multiple additional rows of attribute-value pairs -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cols {
  width:100%;
}

.cols > div:nth-child(even) {
  width:67%;
  float:right;
  background-color:red;
}

.cols > div:nth-child(odd) {
   width:33%;
   float:left;
   background-color:green;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @haxtbh, this is helpful. However, it would be really great to be able to use Bootstrap's classes as these provide responsive layouts. I understand that this can be done by custom CSS too, but it would be great to have it available "out of the box".

Comment: You wont get this out the box because its not really how it should be used. I don't really see the reason why you don't put the classes on each row as intended. There is no benefit from using a class on the parent.

Comment: On my current template, I have 11 attribute-value pairs, so I would save 20 ((11-1)*2) classes if I could specify this on a parent or template element. This would improve brevity (and, in my opinion, legibility) and reduce room for errors.